# Reoccuring Events in Calendar

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, calendar

I am trying to design a workflow which will create a task list based on calendar entries in a SharePoint calendar.

When a new calendar event is created, a task is create with this.

For single events this is simple enough, however recurring events is a different story.

I can detect if the event is reoccurring with `CurrentItem:Recurrence` and I know the data for the type of recurrence is stored in `CurrentItem:RecurrenceData` however if I output the data to the task description the only information I am getting out of this field is:

Recurrence Data: suFALSE

How can I get meaningful data out of this field in SharePoint Designer?

I am using Office 365 SharePoint (2013)

Comment: could you add a code snippet to understand it better?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the XML formatted data from the RecurrenceData field from within the workflow by setting a variable to the RecurrenceData value As String.
[image]

If you want to store it in the task description field, you need to set the task description field to type "Multiple lines of text" with the "Plain text" setting.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Check the Task to see if the `Recurring` field is set to `Yes` and there has been a change in the `Status` of the Task. If both these conditions were not met then the workflow stops and it logs information accordingly.
2. Then we need to create new task sample list. Here also set `Start` and `Finish` dates to the calculated columns.
3. Finally, the `StatusCopy` column is updated to the new value of the Task Status, thereby enabling the cross check in Step 1 to determine if the `Status` changes again.